# How to tell which IP is valid only based on the given subnet mask

Tags: ip, subnet

I'm looking for a way to tell which IP is valid only based on the given subnet mask.

For example : given the subnet mask : 255.255.255.240, is 195.206.108.25 a valid IP? Why?

Comment: You can't use the subnet mask for this.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't understand? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The subnet mask is only useful if you also have the network prefix.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Actually this is a question I'm facing : http://pik.vn/2014d8df73e2-3e8b-4d2a-abe9-606bad30d266.jpeg , maybe I misunderstood the question

Comment: Without further information, they're all valid.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, what about my answer below?

Comment: @t.thielemans: It's possible to answer the question "Given mask `M` and network `N`, is IP `v` valid?"  But if `N` is not given, then the answer is always "yes" (other than for reserved IP addresses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IP:** 195.206.108.25

**MASK:** 255.255.255.240 (/28)

> ```
>      255.255.255.255
>   -  255.255.255.240
> ---------------------
>        0.  0.  0. 15
> ```

```
Network: 195.206.108.0/28
Usable hosts: 195.206.108.1-195.206.108.14
Broadcast: 195.206.108.15

Network: 195.206.108.16/28
Usable hosts: 195.206.108.17-195.206.108.30
Broadcast: 195.206.108.31
```

So 195.206.108.25 is a valid IP address of the 195.206.108.16/28 network. (correct me if I'm wrong)